# How to add Search Kit to CRM profile

Tags: custom-reports

Do you need to add Search Kit to your CRM profile?  My permissions have recently been upgraded to Administrator but still cannot see Search Kit.

Answer (score 2):

(a) Under Administer - Users and Permissions - Permissions, you'll see a link for either Drupal Access Control or Wordpress Access Control depending on your CMS. Click that and see if the role has "SearchKit: edit and delete searches".

(b) Is searchkit installed? Check under Administer - System Settings - Extensions.